# Spring How to implement and test CSRF security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

in my Spring Boot to project trying to implement CSRF security.

For now these are the steps I have taken:

1. Added the following dependencies in the pom.xml file.

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Created the following login.jsp file

> ```
> <center>
>  <h1>Welcome to Spring Boot Security</h1>
>  <h2>Login Page</h2>
>  
>  <form method="POST" action="/login">
>       User Name : <input type="text" name="username" value="user"/><br><br>
>       Password  : <input type="password" name="password" value="password"/><br><br>
>       <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
>       <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
>  </form>
>  </center>
> ```

3. Created the configuration code that contains a CSFR activation and deactivation flag linked to a variable in the application.properties file.

   public class CSRFSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Value("${security.enable-csrf}")
   private boolean csrfEnabled;

   ```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();

        if (csrfEnabled) {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
    }
   ```

security:
enable:
csrf: true

But if I make REST calls I don't see any logs. How can I verify that CSFR security is implemented correctly? Do you have any ideas ?? Any other suggestions besides what I have already implemented?
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: It is a bit strange that if you set `enable-csrf` to `true`, then you disable CSRF. Perhaps you meant to have that logic reversed? As far as verifying that CSRF is enabled, there are various ways. You can write a [test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-csrf), manually test a POST without the CSRF token, enable trace logs and look for the `CsrfFilter`. I suggest starting with the Spring Security [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/) to get a better understanding of Spring Security and CSRF.

Comment: Could you post a test example to verify that CSRF is active, please ??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add tests just like in [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf).

For example, while csrf is enabled you can test both without and with a csrf token, and you should receive `isForbidden()` and `isCreated()` respectively:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SecurityWithCsrfConfig.class, ...})
public class CsrfEnabledIntegrationTest extends CsrfAbstractIntegrationTest {

  @Test
  public void givenNoCsrf_whenAddFoo_thenForbidden() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(
      post("/foos").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .content(createFoo())
                   .with(testUser())
      ).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
  }

  @Test
  public void givenCsrf_whenAddFoo_thenCreated() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(
      post("/foos").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .content(createFoo())
                   .with(testUser()).with(csrf())
     ).andExpect(status().isCreated());
  }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments by @eleftheria-stein-kousathana, I'd also suggest you test your logic around enabling and disabling your csrf. As the naming of the flag `csrfEnabled` looks counter intuitive, as it is actually disables csrf when set to `true`.